# How extract only dictionary keys from keys?

Tags: dictionary, graph

How to transform this type of dictionary:

```
       {"A":
       {"B":{"w":0.4},
       "C":{"w":0.6},
       "D":{"w":0.8}}, 
       "D":
       {"C":{"w":0.2},
       "A":{"w":0.8}}}
```

To this structure:

```
    {"A":{"B":0.4,"C":0.6,"D":0.8}, 
    "D":{"C":0.2,"A":0.8}}
```

Thank you

Comment: What programming language does this relate to?

Answer (score 0):

Given

```py
x = {
  "A":{
    "B":{"w":0.4},
    "C":{"w":0.6},
    "D":{"w":0.8}},
  "D":{
    "C":{"w":0.2},
    "A":{"w":0.8}}}
```

you can use

```py
w = {d:{i:x[d][i]['w'] for i in x[d]} for d in x}
```

or

```py
g = lambda d: d['w'] if 'w' in d else {i:g(d[i]) for i in d}
w = g(x)
```

to generate the structure you want.

Comment: What programming language are you and the questioner using?

Comment: @BigRon I am using python, 2.7 to be exact (I think same code works for third python as well).